# Create UEFI/BIOS chip dump from within Linux

Tags: uefi, bios, flash-memory

Some people recommend using `flashrom` to create backup dump of a PC's UEFI/BIOS SPI flash contents. However, `flashrom` does not work with all platforms. Sometimes people recommend finding the address range of the SPI flash from `/dev/iomem` and then using that in combination with `dd` to extract it from `/dev/mem`. The problem with this is that `/dev/iomem` pretty much always reports that the `System ROM` resides in the range `0x000f0000-0x000fffff`, which is 64 KiB whilst the SPI flash is almost always larger than that.

Thus, how can one extract the contents of the SPI flash while running Linux on the target system and without using a SPI flash clip? I know that there is a way to do it because I found it once and I used it to extract a firmware image which UEFITools was able to open, but I've forgotten what that method is.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what you believe, there is *not* always a way to do it.

And since every hardware is different, every firmware is different, there's also no unified way of doing it on machines where the memory is actually somewhere mapped into io space.

Sorry. What you think exists just doesn't exist *in general*; it might exist in a specific way for your specific board.
That's why you get a different "uefi update utility" for Windows for every single motherboard vendor.

> I know that there is a way to do it because I found it once and I used it to extract a firmware image which UEFITools was able to open, but I've forgotten what that method is.

Sounds like a firmware specific solution. Depends on your board!

Comment: Ironically it *used* to be technically possible on nearly any system supporting upgrades (if the firmware flash was accessible for updating, it was usually accessible for reading) — of course the necessary tools might not always exist. Now that most motherboard manufacturers have switched to using UEFI capsules for firmware updates, it’s no longer necessary for flash devices to be accessible after boot, which means it might not even be technically possible any longer.

Comment: Well, I was able to dump the flash chip of my fit-PC3 *somehow*. The image could even be opened by UEFITool. But, maybe my memory is fuzzy. Maybe I used `flashrom`, but I swear I remember using `dd`.

Comment: The firmware flash chip needs to be mapped into memory for the computer to work, so surely it can be found in `/dev/mem`. The question become at what address range amd how to find that out. Would `dmidecode` tell us the address to look at?

Comment: @Melab No, it does not at all have to be mapped to memory.

Comment: Am I wrong about `/proc/iomem` always saying that `System ROM` resides at `0x000f0000-0x000fffff` on x86?

Comment: That is not what you think it is. That contains the IBM PC (ca 1980) function table with the emulated BIOS functionality entry points

Comment: @sinabala What is not what I think it is? The `System ROM` entry?